# A mixed of the Dedekind zeta function and the L-function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, l-functions

I have recently come across the following function, which seems like a "mix" between the Dedekind zeta function and the L-function:

$\sum_I\frac{\chi_k(N(I))}{N(I)^s}$

where $\chi_k(n)$ is the Kronecker symbol $(k/n)$ and $I$ runs through the ideals of a quadratic number field. For the original $L$-function, one can use Gauss sums to come up with the identity

$L(1,\chi_k)=-\frac{\tau(\chi_k)}{k}\sum_{m=0}^{k-1}\chi_k(m)\log(1-\omega^{-m})$

where $\omega:=e^{2\pi i/k}$. I was wondering if one can generalize Gauss sums, in order to prove a similar expression for the "mix"-function above?

I have tried generalizing myself, but it has not led me anywhere yet. Also, I can not seem to find anything in the litterature about it.

Comment: The map $I \mapsto \chi_k(N(I))$ defines a character of the group of fractional ideals prime to $k$, so I think what you have is the $L$-function of a Hecke character of the quadratic field.